# Having trouble loading ios/main.bundlejs for ios react-native itc deploy

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am trying to do my first deploy to itc for my ios app that now contains a react-native view.
i created the bundle using

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

But i cant seem to figure out the syntax to switch the jsCodeLocation to use the new bundle. Most  guides i find are in obj-c, and cant figure out whats wrong with the command i have. when i set a break point here i find it returns jsCodeLocation nil.

```
  func loadReactNativeView () {
    //let jsCodeLocation : URL = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index.ios", fallbackResource: nil)

    let jsCodeLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle", subdirectory: "ios")

    let rootView : RCTRootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "HealthStorylines", initialProperties: [:], launchOptions: [:])
    rootView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174, green: 0.4862745106, blue: 0.1411764771, alpha: 1)
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height - 49)
    rootView.frame = frame
    self.view.addSubview(rootView)
  }
```

Help much appreciated and need advice on how to debug

Answer (score 0):

I am using this approach at the AppDelegate.swift. I know the answer may be late, but for anyone else getting here

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  let jsCodeLocation: URL = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource:nil)
  let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: GlobalConstants.appName, initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: launchOptions)
  let rootViewController = UIViewController()
  rootViewController.view = rootView

  self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

  return true
}
```

Where GlobalConstants.appName is an string with your app name "ExampleApp"